# Jenkins fails to start on centOS7

Tags: linux, jenkins, centos7

I am using jenkins on my centOS7/linux server. When I start jenkins and checked the status it showed me like this.

```
>jenkins.service - Jenkins Service  
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset:  >  disabled)  
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-02-20 22:52:19 PST; 22s   > ago  
>  Process: 40251 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/local/bin/jenkins.war    
>(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  
> Main PID: 40251 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  
>Feb 20 22:52:19 CentOS7 systemd[1]: Started Jenkins Service.  
>Feb 20 22:52:19 CentOS7 systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins Service...  
>Feb 20 22:52:19 CentOS7 java[40251]: Error: Unable to access jarfile >/usr/l...ar  
>Feb 20 22:52:19 CentOS7 systemd[1]: jenkins.service: main process exited, >c...RE  
>Feb 20 22:52:19 CentOS7 systemd[1]: Unit jenkins.service entered failed state.  
>Feb 20 22:52:19 CentOS7 systemd[1]: jenkins.service failed.  
>Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

So I uninstalled the jenkins `sudo yum remove jenkins` by this command, and installed it again `sudo yum install jenkins`.
Now again facing the same issue.

Can anyone tell me what to do.

Thanks!!

Comment: And also tell me how to uninstall jenkins completely from the centos7/linux server?

Comment: Can anyone tell me..How to make it active state as running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can install Jenkins, you need to setup a Java virtual machine on your system

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

And set two environment variables: `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`.

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
echo 'export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
```

Then install jenkins and allow inbound traffic on port `8080`.

You can see more details from [how to install jenkins on Centos 7](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-jenkins-on-centos-7).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already installed java..Till yesterday my jenkins works fine in my server..Today when i start  jenkins it fails.

Comment: @keerth  Check out your environment variables.I suppose you set it for current shell last time.And when you open another shell,they're gone.

Answer (score 1):

As per Jun, Jenkins required Java 11.
Refer :
[Required Java version for Jenkins](https://community.jenkins.io/t/java-11-required-for-jenkins-2-357/2848)

at first you cannot get clue, on run `systemctl status jenkins.service`
until I try to change JENKINS_USER on `/etc/init.d/jenkins` to root, and show me

Jenkins requires Java versions [17, 11] but you are running with Java 1.8 from `/usr/lib/j`

Once I upgraded Java to 11 then it started working.